# Page freezes for seconds when ajax post working

Tags: ajax, jquery

When i use jquery's $.post ajax function, page freezes for 2-3 seconds and then data received. Freezing time can change depends on the data received.

How can i prevent this ?

EDIT:

COde i am using, it actually receives very large data

```
$.post("../ajax_updates.php", {  time: last_update }, function(data) { 
   if (data) {
   if (data != "") {
    $("#news_feed").prepend($(data).fadeIn('slow'));
    }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Can you supply the JavaScript code in question? Sounds like you're doing something in a callback that is pausing all other activity on the page...

Comment: @zerkms async is on default settings, i didnt touch it

Comment: Modifying the DOM can be hard on the browser - is $(data) a large element? have you tested with a very small amount of markup?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you load big amount of data through JavaScript this is normal, the problem is caused because your request is `synchronous` which will make your browser to wait this request to end before do anything else.
You need to make your request `asynchronous`

P.S. Use $.get instead of $.post to get information from the server, in some cases - specially if you code work under Windows IIS you will get an error about that.

P.S-1. And it make sense $.get is for getting data from the server and $.post is for sending data.

Try this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    async: true
});

$.get("../ajax_updates.php", {  time: last_update }, function(data) { 
  if (data && data != "") {
    $("#news_feed").prepend($(data).fadeIn('slow'));
  }
});
```

Comment: how can i handle the additional data on php when i use $.get ?

Comment: If you don't like to modify your script it's okay to use $.post, if you change the $.post to $.get you need to change little bit of your script because i think that he will wait for $_POST['last_update'] but u pass it in $_GET php array.

Comment: and yes it doesnt freeze now, $.get is the thing i needed!

Comment: Great solution friend ;) (y)

Answer (score 2):

When you send the ajax request make sure that async is set to true.  If it is set to false, the browser will freeze untill a response is received.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: $.post does not have async option, by default it is set to true